# Absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k+1}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k+1}$$

This problem is asking me to prove if this **series** is **absolutely convergent**, **conditionally convergent** or **divergent**, but I don't know how to start when I begin with the absolute convergence. Can anyone give me a hint on how to do it? Thanks

Comment: no, is the square root of k, not the whole thing

Comment: So my edit in the post is correct? Anyway, you should visit the Help center for formatting tips http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 2):

For conditionally convergence use the Leibniz convergence theorem, the sequence is decreasing and converges to zero. But the series does not converge absolute:$$\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k+1}\geq \frac{1}{k+1}$$ which does diverge.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may write, as $k \to \infty$, using a Taylor series expansion,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k+1}&=\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\frac1{1+\frac1{\sqrt{k}}}
\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt{k}}+O\left(\frac1k\right)\right)
\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{k}}-\frac1k+O\left(\frac1{k^{3/2}}\right)
\end{align}
$$ thus the given series
$$
\sum_{k\ge k_0}\frac{(-1)^k\sqrt{k}}{k+1}=\sum_{k\ge k_0}\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}-\sum_{k\ge k_0}\frac{(-1)^k}k+\sum_{k\ge k_0}O\left(\frac1{k^{3/2}}\right)
$$ is conditionally convergent, not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Can this be done by limit comparison or basic comparison test?

Comment: @user354632 Using the last equality one sees that, *as a sum of three convergent series*, it is a convergent series.

Comment: @user354632 As given in my answer above, by comparison, as $k \to \infty$, $\frac{\sqrt{k}}{k+1} \sim \frac1{\sqrt{k}}$ and the series is not absolutely convergent.